# Using VBA in Microsoft Office/Excel

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I am a process automation engineer and one of the tools we work with utilizes VBA in Excel to facilitate the configuration of the controllers we provide with our solutions.

The tool also uses OPC Factory Server (OPC DA protocol) to establish communication with the hardware.

Recently, I replaced my work laptop with a new one and now I am having issues running our Excel tool on my new device.

I am not experienced with VBA programming and the people who originally developed this tool are no longer with the company.

Based on the research I have done, I understand that the main problem preventing this tool from running properly on my machine is that some object/library references need to be updated.

I am not sure what to do beyond this point to be honest.

Here are some screenshots:

Error message

[image: 1]

Missing components

[image: 2]

Appreciate any help and please let me know if I can provide any further information.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Appears require to register the type library See regasm.exe https://www.geeksengine.com/article/register-dll.html

Comment: You require the OPC DA automation add-on for the code to work. A quick google shows this is no longer supported though (https://opcfoundation.org/developer-tools/samples-and-tools-classic/automation-wrapper/). The code likely requires rewriting. I would suggest contacting them and see if they can help: https://opcfoundation.org/about/contact-us/

Comment: https://www.matrikonopc.com/products/opc-archiving/excel-reporter.aspx (Install)

Comment: @Tragamor Was just researching the type library must be registered to download it etc.  If they still have the access to the old pc or a copy of the type library files and manually   register it using regasm.

Comment: The file name of the .DLL you are missing is `C:\windowsSysWow64\OPCDAAuto.dll` it will be on any PC that runs OPC Factory Server, so copy it if you find one. I think I am right in saying that this is a wrapper (an interface to VBA) for an executable that actually communicates with your factory hardware, you need to find that too.

Comment: Hello everyone!
Thanks for your comments.
I have been busy with something else, so it took me a while before I was able to get back to this issue.
I was able to get the dll file from my old PC (thankfully it hasn't been formatted by our IT department yet).
I copied the file to SysWOW64 and registered the dll and everything is working fine now.
Thanks for the help!